# Used media query and zoom to tweak image for mobile, but

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, zooming

I've used the following CSS to resize an image for the mobile version of [this site](http://ochreand.blue/).

```
.title-desc-image {}
@media only screen and (max-width:560px) {
  .title-desc-image {
    zoom:70%;
    margin:auto;
  }
}
```

However, you'll see that I'm left with a light grey from where the bottom of the image would have landed.

Is there a way to get rid of this, or a better way to resize the image?

Thanks.

Comment: Please [create an example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue you are experiencing. You might think that all users can see the same issue you are seeing, but that may or may not be true; creating a verifiable example of the issue makes sure that all users can experience the issue. **[See this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)**

Comment: Thanks @Quoid. I'm building the site off of Squarespace, so I couldn't create a verifiable example if I tried I'm afraid. I have only basic CSS skills, which is why I guess my question is neither thorough nor helpful enough to others. I'll figure it out. But appreciate the links - will keep this in mind in the future.

Comment: Do you have the option to use a css background image instead of a html img? if so see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/msechrest/sLuspxfn/embedded/result/). although the text goes off screen at a mobile resolution you may be able to play around with this. If I were you I would separate the text from the image so i could make sure the cut off doesn't happen.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew. I do have the option to use text easily. But using an img this way was backup because I can't figure out a way to knockout the overlay using the text to get the same design effect. I guess there's an option to hide this img at mobile res and call up another version using media queries, but as I'm building off Sqaurespace's dev platform, I'm having to dive through a lot of code and figure out the directories. Thanks for the advice. Will keep at it.